# Reduce time of MySQL JOIN statement execution

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, join

I have a notifcation system like in Facebook using the following MySQL statement:

```
SELECT  
n.`id`,n.`content_id`,n.`site_id`,n.`creator_uid`,n.`type`,
nu.`id` AS nuid, nu.`uid` AS nu_uid, nu.`date`,
nr.`id` AS nrid, nr.`uid` AS nr_uid, nr.`is_read`,
u.`gender`

FROM `notification` AS n
LEFT JOIN `notification_user` AS nu ON nu.`nid` = n.`id`
LEFT JOIN `notification_read` AS nr ON nr.`nid` = n.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON u.`id` = nu.`uid` 
WHERE 
    nu.`uid` != '".$_SESSION['uid']."' AND nr.`uid` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'
    OR
    (
    nu.`uid` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."' AND n.`type` = 'credits'
    )
ORDER BY date DESC, nu.`id` DESC
```

It should only display the notifications for this specific user I'm logged in as. But now I've more than 22500 records on the notification table and I'm always getting an "maximum execution time exceeded" error.

Can I change this query somehow to reduce the time getting the wanted records? Maybe remove the join and execute more queries?

EDIT: **Added Table Overview**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creator_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22759 ;
```

.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notification_read` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_read` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `nid` (`nid`),
  KEY `nid_2` (`nid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=45342 ;
```

.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notification_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22813 ;
```

Comment: Use `explain select ...` to see the exec plan and add the indexes of your tables to the question

Comment: I suppose you are join via primary keys. Do you have any indexes in your tables? n.type could be indexed. But 22500 records is not much.

Comment: @Kiwi Juicer: Every `id` field is indexed as primary key. @juergen d: I don' t really now how to do that and where I'm supposed to do that. Can I do that in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: do you need to join the user table only for the gender?
maby order by id instead of date?

Comment: @RolandStarke: Yes. I also removed this to see if this is taking too much time but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Try posting the tables schema so that everyone can have a better view.

Comment: I added the table schema in my question.

Comment: First thing I would try is to split that in to a pair of UNIONed queries, which will remove the OR from the WHERE clause. Then the 2 joins can be tailored to the actual query for that part of the WHERE clause

Comment: Can you run an explain on your statement by putting it in front of your select statement like EXPLAIN SELECT...  Run that in phpmyadmin and then post the results here again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the statement up in to a pair of SELECTs, and UNIONing the results together:-

```
(SELECT  
n.`id`,n.`content_id`,n.`site_id`,n.`creator_uid`,n.`type`,
nu.`id` AS nuid, nu.`uid` AS nu_uid, nu.`date`,
nr.`id` AS nrid, nr.`uid` AS nr_uid, nr.`is_read`,
u.`gender`
FROM `notification` AS n
INNER JOIN `notification_user` AS nu ON nu.`nid` = n.`id`
LEFT JOIN `notification_read` AS nr ON nr.`nid` = n.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON u.`id` = nu.`uid` 
WHERE nu.`uid` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."' AND n.`type` = 'credits')
UNION
(SELECT  
n.`id`,n.`content_id`,n.`site_id`,n.`creator_uid`,n.`type`,
nu.`id` AS nuid, nu.`uid` AS nu_uid, nu.`date`,
nr.`id` AS nrid, nr.`uid` AS nr_uid, nr.`is_read`,
u.`gender`
FROM `notification` AS n
LEFT JOIN `notification_user` AS nu ON nu.`nid` = n.`id`
INNER JOIN `notification_read` AS nr ON nr.`nid` = n.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON u.`id` = nu.`uid` 
WHERE nu.`uid` != '".$_SESSION['uid']."' AND nr.`uid` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."')
ORDER BY date DESC, nu.`id` DESC
```

This should allow MySQL to use indexes effectively on each part of the query. The first part of the query requires a notification_user record so you can use an INNER JOIN there, while the 2nd requires a notification_read record so you can use an INNER JOIN there. Both of those should cut the number of rows to process.

Add an index on the uid field on the notification_user table

Add an index on the uid field on the notification_read table